# i've been making a discord bot on replit. it's been working perfectly then today it broke

Tags: python, discord

my bot has been running perfectly on replit for 2 days now. I used `replit servers` and `uptimerobot` to keep it up and running and it worked flawlessly until suddenly the bot goes offline.

I check the code and it has stopped working all it gives me is this error code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import discord
  File "/home/runner/discord-bot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from .client import Client
  File "/home/runner/discord-bot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 33, in <module>
    import aiohttp
  File "/home/runner/discord-bot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .client import (
  File "/home/runner/discord-bot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 35, in <module>
    from . import hdrs, http, payload
  File "/home/runner/discord-bot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/http.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .http_parser import (
  File "/home/runner/discord-bot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/http_parser.py", line 15, in <module>
    from .helpers import NO_EXTENSIONS, BaseTimerContext
  File "/home/runner/discord-bot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/helpers.py", line 48, in <module>
    from typing_extensions import Protocol
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'typing_extensions'
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally I use replit as well this seems like a package error, try deleting the package configuration files found on your repl and try re running the program so it'll re install your packages. If this doesn't work try running `pip install typing_extensions` in the shell.